# Threads Block vs Time

Tags: gpgpu

I am developing a code that depends on running many threads blocks on a GPU.Each block consists of juts 32 threads and all threads doing the same instructions but with different data. Now I plot the number of block vs. time. I got a figure looks like a stair. Any one can help me to interpret  why it looks like a stair. I could post the figure because I have to have at least 10 reputation, but if you interested please send me your email and I will send you the figure. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GPU is probably capable of running several blocks (say, n) simultaneously. Then 1 to n blocks will take same time to complete.

Comment: I think this should answer my question especially if we consider that all resources are available like the number of registers and shared memory etc.But the controller is the number of blocks.